# Excel Count if cell receive "Formula Omits Adjust Cell"

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I want to count cells that receive the "Formula Omits Adjust Cell" message.

Is there a way around it?

I've tried conditional formatting to highlight cells that contain "Errors" but it doesn't work.

Any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: That is not error. Check your result.

Answer (score 2):

Place this code in a module

```
Function omit(rng As Range)

For Each cel In rng
  If cel.Errors.Item(xlOmittedCells).Value = True Then
    cnt = cnt + 1
  End If
Next cel
omit = cnt

End Function
```

Call the function like

`=omit(A1:F30)`

For the  parameter use only the required range, otherwise the run-time will be longer. (e.g. selecting the whole sheet)

the count of the cells which has the message **Formula Omits Adjacent Cells** will be displayed in the cell.

[image]

Comment: Did you test it? Code always returns 0 for me. However changing `cel.Errors.Item(xlOmittedCells).Value` to `cel.Errors(5).Value` gives correct result

Comment: Both works for me.

Comment: Strange. Only the latter works for me

Comment: Thank you both. 
Yes only after changing to `cel.Errors(5).Value` gives correct result for me

Comment: I attached the screenshot of test to show the result of the function. @user